# Ignore specific key press in textbox

Tags: c#, unity, gui, interface

there is a text box on GUI in my application created using Unity3D. in the textbox user can input only the keys of "A-Z", "0-9" , "enter key" , "." and "," other key press should be ignored (not should print in textbox when typing). how to do this in Unity3D C#

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're using [GUI.TextField](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.TextField.html)?

It doesn't appear that there's a built-in way to restrict the text field's legal input set, however, you can achieve the validation behavior you want by writing a script:

```
public class LimitInput : MonoBehaviour {
  public void OnGUI() {
    text = GUI.TextField(..., text);
    text = /* replace offending text here */
  }

  string text = string.Empty;
}
```

A simple implementation of the replacement might be along the lines of `text = text.Replace("!", "")` for example (to remove all `!` characters). To implement the specifics of your request, you'll probably want [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).